# Avoiding write skews in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use Spring Data MongoDB transactions to avoid write skew errors. [This diagram](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/49154776/153240259-f4eee7a3-db2d-4150-8b93-721e0f863a6b.png) explains the flow that happens in my example. I also posted the source code as a whole in [this repository](https://github.com/jjarzynski/mongo-txample).

My service method that reads and updates the same document is `@Transactional`:

```kotlin
fun nextMessage(id: Int, text: String) = transactionReadWrite(id, text)
    ?.let { messages.save(it) }

@Transactional
fun transactionReadWrite(id: Int, text: String) = threads.findById(id)
    ?.write(text)
    ?.let { (threadUpdate, previousLatest) ->
        threads.save(threadUpdate)
        log.info("Replacing \"${previousLatest.text}\" with \"${threadUpdate.latestMessage.text}\"")
        previousLatest
    }
```

But when I call `nextMessage()` with 5 different inputs in parallel, I can see some of them reading the same values at the same time, and then successfully updating the document:

```
15:37:06.964 : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:1264}] to localhost:27017
15:37:07.308 : Replacing "0" with "3"
15:37:07.308 : Replacing "0" with "4"
15:37:07.310 : Replacing "0" with "1"
15:37:07.430 : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:1265}] to localhost:27017
15:37:07.430 : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:1266}] to localhost:27017
15:37:07.435 : Replacing "1" with "2"
15:37:07.440 : Replacing "1" with "5"
15:37:07.447 : Replacing "5" with "another one"
```

**How do you avoid write skew errors with Spring Data MongoDB transactions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the diagram, B3.update should not succeed, you need to use optmistic locking in the update, like `updateOne({_id:xx, text:"1"}, $set: { text: "3" })` that will return `0 modified`

Then Bobby needs to find the current entity and attempt the update again.